# How to print only solution sheet in the end of the document in probsoln package

Tags: probsoln

I use:

```
\newproblem{1}{bla bla bla}{ble ble ble}
```

in an external file.tex.

Then in my main file, I use:

```
\loadallproblem....

\begin{enumerate}

\foreachproblem[...]{\item \thisproblem}

\end{enumerate}
```

The question is how can I print only solution in the end of document. Somebody help me!
P/S: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you add a MWE: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that It'll be easier to know what you want

Comment: Have a look at [this sample file](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/probsoln/samples/sample5.tex) provided with the `probsoln` package. Basically, you need to put `\hideanswers` before you display the questions, and later put `\showanswers` and iterate through the dataset again.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thank you very much!!!
Can you give me prob-easy2.tex and prob-probspaces2.tex to run.

Comment: They're in the [samples](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/probsoln/samples/) directory.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot
Really useful. Those are exactly what I want.